# Using jQuery to Read JSON Returned from ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I have a simple C# Class, called Employee which has two properties, Name, Age.
I need to create a list of employees and serialize into JSON and access in jquery.

I have successfuly converted in to JSON.
But i stuck with retreive through the Jquery.

```
public class Employee
{   
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IList<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>() {        
    new Employee() { Name = "XXX", Age=20},
    new Employee() { Name = "YYY", Age=24}
    new Employee() { Name = "kamal", Age=24}
};

System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer objectSerializer = new  System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();    
string jsonObj = objectSerializer.Serialize(employeeList);
Response.Write(jsonObj);
}
```

Any idea..??

Thank in advance.

Comment: Do you have anything with jQuery so far? You might want to look at `jQuery.getJSON`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write the json object in a script tag and assign it to some variable in order to use it. Try this

```
Response.Write("<script type='text\javascript\> var employeeObj = "+jsonObj+"</script>");
```

Usage in jQuery

```
//Looping through employeeObj using each method. Inside each this points to each item in the array and you can use this.Name and this.Age to retreive the values.
$.each(employeeObj, function(){
    alert("Name: " + this.Name + " Age: "+ this.Age);
});
```

Comment: Where are you trying to use this object?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax(
   {url: "your url to get data", 
   type="get", 
   dataType: "json", 
   success: function(data) { //data is your json
   }
);
```

that is ajax call, but if you want to access it as variable you should write it through c# like this

```
String.Format("<script language="javascript">
  var myJson = {0};
</script>", jsonObj)
```

Then you can access it from javascript like

```
  myJson;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Json.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

Use the javascript file and use

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(string);
```